# Vertically and horizontally center text inside tabular

Tags: tables

I want to center horizontally and vertically all text inside the table for example in the sample code, the text 'angular velocity' be in the center of his cell vertically and horizontally while the width of the columns did not change (the width of the 1st and 3rd columns is 2cm and the 2nd and 4th columns by 5cm).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.35}
        \captionsetup{justification=centering}
        \caption{
        {List of variables} 
        }
        \label{tbl: List of variables}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{20mm}|p{50mm}|p{20mm}|p{50mm}|}
            \noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
            Variables       & Definition      & Variables       & Definition    \\
            \noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
            $\mathbf{J}  $                      & moment of inertia  matrix  &$\mathbf{C}_{L/B}$ & Direction Cosine Matrix \\
                \hline
   $\bm{q}$&quaternion vector&$\bm{\omega}_{L/B}$& angular velocity relative to LVLH coordinate system expressed in BFCS \\
   \hline
  $\mathbf{M}$& augmented skew-symmetric matrix  &$\sum{T}_{ext}$ & total external torque \\
   \hline
   $\mathbf{h}_B$ &angular momentum vector& $\bm{\omega}_{E/B}$&  angular velocity relative to ECI coordinate system expressed in BFCS \\
   \hline
   $\omega_{wx}$, $\omega_{wy}$, $\omega_{wz}$ & angular velocity of the RWs &$I_w$ & MOI of the RWs \\
   \hline
  $\omega_{j}$& angular velocity& $\bm{\omega}_{E/L}$ & the satellite's angular velocity relative to LVLH coordinate system with respect to ECI \\
   \hline
  $\bm{x}$&state vector & $\bm{u}$ & control torque vector\\
  \hline
  $T_s$ &  sampling time & $T_x$, $T_y$, $T_z$  &  applied torques  \\
  \hline
 $\alpha$, $\beta$ & fractional-order parameters & $\mathbf{Q}$, $\mathbf{R}$&weighting matrices\\
 \hline
   $\omega_{x}$, $\omega_{y}$, $\omega_{z}$& satellite angular velocity& $\bm{\omega}^\times_{L/B}$& the skew-symmetric matrix of the angular velocity  \\
   \hline
    $\bm{T}_{dis}$&disturbance torque&$v$&the velocity  of the satellite\\
   \hline
   $r$& the position of the satellite&&
\\
   \noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your table is wider than `\textwidth` defined by default `article` page out. - - You may consider to increase it by adding `\usepackage{geometry} to document preamble.
- Simple code, which enable desired table formatting you can write by use of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
\caption{List of variables}
\label{tbl: List of variables}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt, hline{3-Y}, vlines, 
             colspec = {*{2}{Q[c,m, mode=math] X[c,m]} },
             colsep  = 4pt,
             row{1}  = {mode=text}
             }
Variables       & Definition    
                    & Variables
                        & Definition                \\
\mathbf{J}      & moment of inertia  matrix  
                    & \mathbf{C}_{L/B}
                        & Direction Cosine Matrix   \\
\bm{q}          & cquaternion vector
                    & \bm{\omega}_{L/B}
                        & angular velocity relative to LVLH coordinate system expressed in BFCS \\
\mathbf{M}      & augmented skew-symmetric matrix  
                    & \sum{T}_{\mathrm{ext}}
                        & total external torque     \\
\mathbf{h}_B    & angular momentum vector
                    & \bm{\omega}_{E/B}
                        & angular velocity relative to ECI coordinate system expressed in BFCS \\
\omega_{wx}, \omega_{wy}, \omega_{wz}
                & angular velocity of the RWs
                    & I_w
                        & MOI of the RWs            \\
\omega_{j}      & angular velocity
                    & \bm{\omega}_{E/L}
                        & the satellite's angular velocity relative to LVLH coordinate system with respect to ECI \\
\bm{x}          & state vector
                    & \bm{u}
                        & control torque vector     \\
T_s             &  sampling time
                    & T_x, T_y, T_z
                        &  applied torques          \\
\alpha, \beta   & fractional-order parameters
                    & \mathbf{Q}, \mathbf{R}
                        & weighting matrices        \\
\omega_{x}, \omega_{y}, \omega_{z}
                & satellite angular velocity
                    & \bm{\omega}^\times_{L/B}
                        & the skew-symmetric matrix of the angular velocity  \\
\bm{T}_{dis}    & disturbance torque
                    & v & the velocity  of the satellite    \\
r               & the position of the satellite
                    &   &                           \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
BTW, to my opinion table will be nicer (more professional looking) if cells contents would be left aligned, not vertical centered, all vertical lines omitted and for horizontal rules used `booktabs` rules for the first, second and last rule:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{List of variables}
\label{tbl: List of variables}
\begin{tblr}{colsep  = 4pt,
             colspec = {@{} *{2}{Q[l, mode=math] X[l, font=\linespread{0.88}\selectfont} @{}},
             row{1}  = {mode=text}
             row{2-Z} = {rowsep=3pt}
             }
    \toprule
Variables       & Definition    
                    & Variables
                        & Definition                \\
    \midrule
\mathbf{J}      & moment of inertia  matrix  
                    & \mathbf{C}_{L/B}
                        & Direction Cosine Matrix   \\
\bm{q}          & cquaternion vector
                    & \bm{\omega}_{L/B}
                        & angular velocity relative to LVLH coordinate system expressed in BFCS \\
\mathbf{M}      & augmented skew-symmetric matrix  
                    & \sum{T}_{\mathrm{ext}}
                        & total external torque     \\
\mathbf{h}_B    & angular momentum vector
                    & \bm{\omega}_{E/B}
                        & angular velocity relative to ECI coordinate system expressed in BFCS \\
\omega_{wx}, \omega_{wy}, \omega_{wz}
                & angular velocity of the RWs
                    & I_w
                        & MOI of the RWs            \\
\omega_{j}      & angular velocity
                    & \bm{\omega}_{E/L}
                        & the satellite's angular velocity relative to LVLH coordinate system with respect to ECI \\
\bm{x}          & state vector
                    & \bm{u}
                        & control torque vector     \\
T_s             &  sampling time
                    & T_x, T_y, T_z
                        &  applied torques          \\
\alpha, \beta   & fractional-order parameters
                    & \mathbf{Q}, \mathbf{R}
                        & weighting matrices        \\
\omega_{x}, \omega_{y}, \omega_{z}
                & satellite angular velocity
                    & \bm{\omega}^\times_{L/B}
                        & the skew-symmetric matrix of the angular velocity  \\
\bm{T}_{dis}    & disturbance torque
                    & v & the velocity  of the satellite    \\
r               & the position of the satellite
                    &   &                           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Answer (score 0):

For Vertically and horizontally centered text, we can use `{\centering\arraybackslash}m{width}` with package `array`. And code for cauterizing Vertically and horizontally the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.35}
        \captionsetup{justification=centering}
        \caption{
        {List of variables} 
        }
        \label{tbl: List of variables}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.2\linewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.4\linewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.2\linewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.4\linewidth}|}
            \noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
            Variables       & Definition      & Variables       & Definition    \\
            \noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
            $\mathbf{J}  $                      & moment of inertia  matrix  &$\mathbf{C}_{L/B}$ & Direction Cosine Matrix \\
                \hline
   $\bm{q}$&quaternion vector&$\bm{\omega}_{L/B}$& angular velocity relative to LVLH coordinate system expressed in BFCS \\
   \hline
  $\mathbf{M}$& augmented skew-symmetric matrix  &$\sum{T}_{ext}$ & total external torque \\
   \hline
   $\mathbf{h}_B$ &angular momentum vector& $\bm{\omega}_{E/B}$&  angular velocity relative to ECI coordinate system expressed in BFCS \\
   \hline
   $\omega_{wx}$, $\omega_{wy}$, $\omega_{wz}$ & angular velocity of the RWs &$I_w$ & MOI of the RWs \\
   \hline
  $\omega_{j}$& angular velocity& $\bm{\omega}_{E/L}$ & the satellite's angular velocity relative to LVLH coordinate system with respect to ECI \\
   \hline
  $\bm{x}$&state vector & $\bm{u}$ & control torque vector\\
  \hline
  $T_s$ &  sampling time & $T_x$, $T_y$, $T_z$  &  applied torques  \\
  \hline
 $\alpha$, $\beta$ & fractional-order parameters & $\mathbf{Q}$, $\mathbf{R}$&weighting matrices\\
 \hline
   $\omega_{x}$, $\omega_{y}$, $\omega_{z}$& satellite angular velocity& $\bm{\omega}^\times_{L/B}$& the skew-symmetric matrix of the angular velocity  \\
   \hline
    $\bm{T}_{dis}$&disturbance torque&$v$&the velocity  of the satellite\\
   \hline
   $r$& the position of the satellite&&
\\
   \noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]